# Gatsby Dynamic Image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, gatsby, responsive-images

I have a problem: this is my Heroes component

```
const Hero = styled.div`
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: flex-end;
background: linear-gradient(to top, #1f1f21 1%, #1f1f21 1%,rgba(25, 26, 27, 0) 100%) , url(${props => props.bgdesktop}) no-repeat top center;
height: 100vh;
background-size: cover; 
@media (max-width:1024px) {
background: linear-gradient(to top, #1f1f21 1%, #1f1f21 1%,rgba(25, 26, 
27, 0) 100%) , url(${props => props.bgtablet}) no-repeat center top;
}
@media (max-width:480px) {
background:linear-gradient(to top, rgba(31, 31, 33, 1) 2%, rgba(31, 31,33, 1) 5%,rgba(25, 26, 27, 0) 100%)  , url(${props => props.bgmobile}) no-repeat center top;
    }
`
class Heroes extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
...
render() {
    return (
<Hero
bgdesktop={this.props.bgdesktop}
bgtablet={this.props.bgtablet}
bgmobile={this.props.bgmobile}/>
)}}
```

Then I added this component to 'pages/Hero.js':

```
export default props => {
const hero = props.location.href
? heroCards.find(h => h.name === props.location.href.substring(28))
: heroCards[0]
return (
<Layout>
<Heroes
        bgdesktop={require(`./../images/BG/${hero.name}_Desktop.jpg`)}
        bgtablet={require(`./../images/BG/${hero.name}_Tablet.jpg`)}
        bgmobile={require(`./../images/BG/${hero.name}_Mobile.jpg`)}
      />
</Layout>
)
}
```

Now, clicking on different buttons on the Home page, I'm redirected different pages that take different bg depending on 'name' included in heroes.js (located in costants folder). It works on local but not on production and the problem is gatsby that doesn't allow that '{require(./../images/BG/${hero.name}_Desktop.jpg)}'. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need `require` for this. 
Why not use the prop you pass and bake that into a string literal that you insert into the component (without require and outside of the return)?

```
const mobilePath = `./../images/BG/${props.bgmobile}_Mobile.jpg`;
const desktopPath = `./../images/BG/${props.bgdesktop}_Desktop.jpg`;

return(
  <Heroes mobile={mobilePath} desktop={desktopPath} />
)
```

EDIT: the `substring` part could be added in either `<Heroes>` before passing  the prop. Or by filtering the prop in `<Hero>` and passing that variable instead of the prop